# Вывод массива php в график

Tags: jquery, массивы, php, javascript

Добрый день. Посоветуйте какую-нибудь понятную и красивую библиотеку JavaScript или JQuery из множества существующих, с помощью которой можно было бы вывести данные из массива php. Желательно чтобы был демо-пример (где из php передаются в js данные и формируется график), так времени мало очень на изучение теоретических аспектов  графических библиотек.

Comment: Посмотрите ответы здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/316858/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-js-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0

Comment: Kendo UI, ей пользуясь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользовался [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), все, что надо было мне в нем есть :) 
тут есть [примеры](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing/) работы с данными из базы,json и других источников

ps; на закуску [список](http://webification.com/php-js-flash-chart-libraries-roundup) библиотек графиков php-js

Answer (score 2):

[Примеры графиков](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), сделанных на D3js вас, наверняка, вдохновят.

Чтобы не усложнять, вот [простой bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), берущий данные из внешнего текстового файла с табуляцией в качестве разделителя. Можете подставить вместо ссылку вашего php, отдающего ваши данные через таб. Или сразу вывести ваш массив, назначив его js переменной data:

```
<script>

    <?php
    phpData = array(1,2,3,44,555,6666); // ваши данные в массиве php
    printf( "var data = %s;\n", json_encode( phpData));
    ?>

    // далее js код D3, строящий график, используя data
</script>
```